# Wi-Fi only works in Recovery Mode

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi, recovery

I have a new MacBook Pro 2011 (wanted the ports). I recently just installed an SSD and decided to enable TRIM on it. My computer restarts and I have the gray Wi-Fi symbol and "No Hardware Detected". I do everything, resetting NVRAM, SMB, all of it.

However, my Wi-Fi works when I boot into recovery mode. I have no idea why. Is there any fix for this?

EDIT: FIXED BY RE-INSTALLING Sierra

Comment: Does it show up in system information/system profiler?

Comment: Also, by enabling trim, do you mean some app or kext hack or messing with SIP?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add the Wi-Fi service:

1. Open System Preferences → Network and choose **+** to add a service.
2. Choose Interface: Wi-Fi and Create.

   [image]